# Does ServiceWorker send all data to Google or browser vendor?

Tags: service-worker

There are lots of docs about ServiceWorkers, but a very important question remains unanswered:

**If my app uses a ServiceWorker, does all data get proxied through Google (or, for non-Chrome, another browser vendor)**

If so, what are the privacy implications and mitigations? True, it may be encrypted, but it lets the browser vendor track every time someone uses the app, installs it, etc.

Is there any way to use ServiceWorker without proxying through Google? A privacy mode?

Where is this documented? And why is it kept so secret? It's a major privacy issue and should be made very clear.

Answer (score 0):

No, Service Worker does not send any data to Google or any other browser vendor. It also does not do anything by default or without you asking it to do something.

To put it another way, it does what you tell it to do. It runs code you've written just like the webpage.